# Wordpress - How can i merge two images?

Tags: wordpress

As the title says, how can I combine a small picture, small picture will be my logo, and the other image will be that up when I upload an image to the library of wordpress automatically in the pictures I added, it is placed my logo?

Any plugin for this, or how I can integrate this idea into wordpress

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a watermark have a look at:-

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/image-watermark/